# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'

Tags: python, flask

Well, I am writing a Flask project, but when I tried to `python manage.py`

The traceback told me that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app import db,create_app
  File "/home/humbert/2017-sharing-backend/sharing/app/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint, url_prefix='/main')
  File "/home/humbert/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 64, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/humbert/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 951, in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(self, options, first_registration)
  File "/home/humbert/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 154, in register
    deferred(state)
  File "/home/humbert/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 173, in <lambda>
    s.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, view_func, **options))
  File "/home/humbert/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 76, in add_url_rule
    view_func, defaults=defaults, **options)
  File "/home/humbert/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 64, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/humbert/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1043, in add_url_rule
    rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

I think my `manage.py` is right,and I can't figure out the mistake.

The mistake part of `__init__.py` is that:

```
from .main import main as main_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint, url_prefix='/main')

from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix="/auth")

from . import views
```

I really need some help, thanks!

Comment: You must debug your code if you have something left in your code. In my case, I miss one `id`  attribute that has to be added .

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I had a similar problem. In my code I had a line

`@bp.route('/<init:id>/delete', method=('POST'))`

The keyword method needs to be changed to methods(with an s)

Comment: I have the same problem too with my todo flask project when trying to handle:
@app.route('/todos/create', method=['POST'])
your answer helps me to solve the problem by adding 's':
@app.route('/todos/create', methods=['POST'])
Thanks Nicholas Harder.

Comment: Always nice when I can look at older SO posts, and get the right answer, like this... stupid typos, and pylint doesn't catch a lot of stuff in Flask, as it is...

Answer (score 32):

I had encountered a similar problem in my code and just had to change the keyword "*method*" to "*methods*":

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
```

Comment: You just repeated the accepted answer, nearly five months later! Why? LOL

Comment: Why indeed and why does this have so many likes?