# How do I fix the TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errorHandling'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am building a League of Legends website/application for my CS capstone and I am already stuck pulling data from the API.
Here is the code:

```
pip install pantheon

from pantheon import pantheon
import asyncio

server = "euw1"
api_key = "RGAPI-XXXXX" #(api_key is personal and shouldnt be shared)

def requestsLog(url, status, headers):
    print(url)
    print(status)
    print(headers)

panth = pantheon.Pantheon(server, api_key, errorHandling=True, requestsLoggingFunction=requestsLog, debug=True)

async def getSummonerId(name):
    try:
        data = await panth.getSummonerByName(name)
        return (data['id'],data['accountId'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


async def getRecentMatchlist(accountId):
    try:
        data = await panth.getMatchlist(accountId, params={"endIndex":10})
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

async def getRecentMatches(accountId):
    try:
        matchlist = await getRecentMatchlist(accountId)
        tasks = [panth.getMatch(match['gameId']) for match in matchlist['matches']]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

And here is the error when I run it in Visual Studio Code (Python 3.9.10 64 bit)

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\maase\Downloads\apipantheon.ipynb Cell 4' in <cell line: 12>()
      9     print(status)
     10     print(headers)
---> 12 panth = pantheon.Pantheon(server, api_key, errorHandling=True, requestsLoggingFunction=requestsLog, debug=True)
     14 async def getSummonerId(name):
     15     try:

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errorHandling'
```

Do I have to import or install something to fix this?

Comment: The Pantheon class does not expect an `errorHandling` argument. This is the init function signature from the github repo
 https://github.com/Canisback/pantheon/blob/662dcee67eb5f6fbc0a3196cdb575d143fc4962d/pantheon/pantheon.py#L29

Comment: This might be a question for the developers of that package. In the documentation it shows what you've typed, but if you check the actual source code for the class, the class doesn't have the given paramemter. The source shows  `def __init__(self, server, api_key, auto_retry = False, requests_logging_function = None, debug=False):...`

Comment: Link below with the solutions answer sometime ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126772/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-method